# Unable to perform mouse hover in chrome browser using Actions class

Tags: selenium, mousehover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Jqz.jpg)    String selector = "div.tilesGroupTilesHolder div.db_labeldiv:contains("+tileTitle+")"
    Actions action = new Actions(getController().getDriver());
            action.clickAndHold(getController().findElementByJQuerySelector(selector)).perform();
            action.moveToElement(getController().findElementByJQuerySelector(selector)).perform();

Comment: would be usefuul if you provide your DOM or Url to replicate your issue

Comment: Hi dipak, url I cant provide but can provide you with the screenshot.